# Can shareholders compel a company to not pay taxes?

Tags: united-states

Can shareholders compel a company to evade taxes? Logically, if they think it is in their interest the company has to do it. The charter of a corporation is to make money for shareholders, I don't think most charters require the company to follow the law of a specific federal government.

And, they are not aiding or abetting anything. They are just exercising shareholder rights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

Any conduct that demands someone does something unlawfully is unlawful. [Taxes are laws and regulations.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/chapter-I) [Not paying the taxes is unlawful](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/tax_evasion), especially under [26 USC 7201](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/7201). So the shareholders are not only demanding the company to break laws, they **aid and abett** such behavior, making them **also** liable together with the company as there is [18 USC 2](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2):

> (a) Whoever commits an offense against the United States or aids, abets, counsels, commands, induces or procures its commission, is punishable as a principal.
>
> (b) Whoever willfully causes an act to be done which if directly performed by him or another would be an offense against the United States, is punishable as a principal.

It could **also** be inciting to violate laws. It is **not** a shareholder's right to ask for someone to break the law.

Comment: You are correct to assert that shareholders cannot demand the corporation practice tax *evasion.* However, it is perfectly legitimate for shareholders to demand tax *avoidance* as such avoidance is lawful and the corporation owes them a fiduciary duty.

Comment: @Kevin The question specifically asks if they can demand evading taxes, which is unlawful.